# create custom url in codeiginter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-rewriting, custom-url

i want show my products name in url
now i get my product with id and my url display like that.
www.mydomain.com/home/single/1

i want to show my product url with product name Like.
www.mydomain.com/home/single/New-Dell-Laptop

Here is my code that's get post with it's id number.

**Controller**

```
//get all products
public function index()
    {
        $data['products'] = $this->front->get_products();
        $this->load->view('index',$data);
    }

    //get single product
public function single($id)
    {
        $data['product']=$this->front->get_product($id);
        $this->load->view('product',$data);
    }
```

**Model**

```
//get all products
    public function get_products()
    {
        $this->db->select()
                 ->from('vendor_products')
                 ->where('DESC','date_added');
        $data = $this->db->get();
        return $data->result_array();
    }

        //get single product
    public function get_product($id)
    {
        $this->db->select()
                 ->from('vendor_products')
                 ->where('prod_id',$id);
        $data = $this->db->get();
        return $data->first_row('array');
    }
```

**Views**

//show all products index.php

```
<?php foreach($products as $one) : ?>
            //create link for single product
        <a href="<?=base_url();?>home/single/<?=$one['prod_id'];?>">

            <?=$one['product_name'];?>
        </a>
        <p><?=$one['product_price'];?></p>
```

//show single product (product.php)

```
<p><?=$product['product_name'];?></p>
        <p><?=$product['product_price'];?></p>
        <p><?=$product['product_description'];?></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use routes.

In your `config/routes.php`

```
require_once( BASEPATH .'database/DB'. EXT );
$db =& DB();
$query = $db->get('vendor_products');
$result = $query->result();
foreach( $result as $row )
{
    $route["home/single/" . $row->product_name] = "home/single/" . $row->prod_id;
}
```

And then in your view, change

```
<a href="<?=base_url();?>home/single/<?=$one['prod_id'];?>">`
```

by

```
<a href="<?=base_url();?>home/single/<?=$one['product_name'];?>">`
```

Comment: This Error show 

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Use of undefined constant EXT - assumed 'EXT'

Filename: config/routes.php

Line Number: 14

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\onlinemarket\application\config\routes.php
Line: 14
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\onlinemarket\index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once

Comment: The error message message is clear, just replace the first line by `require_once( BASEPATH .'database/DB.php');`. You could have found this by yourself :) Also you should consider @Raphael Schubert's answer

Comment: product image and data not show. which get from database through id

Comment: My Controllers:

`public function vendor_profiles()
 {
  $data['profiles'] = $this->front->vendor_profiles();
  $this->load->view('vendors',$data);
 }
 public function profile($id)
 {
  $data['profile'] = $this->front->vendor_profile($id);
  $this->load->view('profile',$data);
 }`

My Views:

`<?php foreach($profiles as $vendor) : ?>

<a href="<?=base_url();?>home/profile/<?=$vendor['vendor_id'];?>"><img src="<?=base_url();?>uploads/<?=$vendor['ven_img'];?>"></a>

<a href="<?=base_url();?>home/profile/<?=$vendor['vendor_id'];?>"><?=$vendor['ven_firstname'];?></a>

<?php endforeach; ?>`

Comment: show Data view File:

`<p><img src="<?=base_url();?>uploads/<?=$profile['ven_logo'];?>"></p>
<p><img src="<?=base_url();?>uploads/<?=$profile['ven_img'];?>"></p>
<p>First Name : <?=$profile['ven_firstname'];?></p>
<p>Last Name : <?=$profile['ven_lastname'];?></p>
<p>Username : <?=$profile['username'];?></p>
<p>Email : <?=$profile['ven_email'];?></p>`

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be another issue. Please open a new question with detailed information about that new problematic you're facing.  In the meantime, make sure to upvote and click the checkmark if any answer helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

The string you`re humanizing, will be in a field, right?

```
www.mydomain.com/home/single/New-Dell-Laptop
```

So, if you select in database for "New Dell Laptop"

It will return 1 record, right? If so, you can configure something like this on Routes in config.

```
$route['single/{product}'] = 'productController/{product}';
```

Then when you load productController/New-Dell-Laptop

You can use $this->uri->segment(3) to get the value, and search in Database, retrieve page, and show to user.

You should use something like this:

```
www.mydomain.com/home/single/34/New-Dell-Laptop
```

Where 34 will be the id to the page and will be easy to you locate on database, but you should not get troubles to find if you search for "New Dell Laptop"